# Moving Identity 2.0 functions to repository class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I am using identity 2.0 for my application and want to move the data functionalities to repository layer such as the following code:

```
    public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext> {
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) {
        InitializeIdentityForEF(context);
        base.Seed(context);
    }

    //Create User=Admin@Admin.com with password=Admin@123456 in the Admin role        
    public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext db) {
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
```

now the problem is `HttpContext` doesn't live in the repository layer and you have to pass it to that layer. but even if you do that, the call should be coming from the `Web` layer. yet you don't want to include `userManager` in every call to other layers. any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the way to create the user manager on the repository layer:

```
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);               
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "sallen" };

            userManager.Create(user, "password");                    
            roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "admin" });
            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");
```