# ASP Identity 2.0 and ASP.NET MVC Project Structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, migration, asp.net-identity, projects-and-solutions

**I'm beginner in `ASP.NET MVC5`.**

My project solution has the structure as described in [ASP.NET MVC5 Pro](http://www.apress.com/9781430265290):

```
Solution
 -Project.Domain    --- C# Class Library
 -Project.WebUI     --- Empty ASP.Net MVC Project Template
 -Project.UnitTests
```

And I want to use `ASP Identity 2.0` in it.

In Project.Domain I have `Concrete` (contexts, their initializers) and `Entities` (data models) foldiers.

I installed `Identity 2.0 Samples` as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics).

I split the `IdentityModels.cs` file into `ApplicationDbContext.cs` and `ApplicationUser.cs`, and put them in `Concrete` and `Entities` foldiers respectively.

Also in `Concrete` foldier I have `EFDbContext.cs` - separate from `ApplicationDbContext` context (they use the same database connection).

I wanted to store `AppicationDbInitializer` class (from `Project.WebUI\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs`) in `Project.Domain` since `ApplicationDbContext` contains *static constructor* which set `ApplicationDbInitializer`,  but then it turned out that `Project.Domain` and `Project.WebUI` have **cyclic dependence**, so I decided not move it and set database initializer in `Global.asax.cs` from `Project.WebUI`.

Then problems began. For some reasons method `ApplicationDbInitializer.Seed` isn't working and `role "Admin"` isn't created. 
Then I decided to try enable migrations. I enabled migrations in `Project.Domain` (as described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537558/multiple-db-contexts-in-the-same-db-and-application-in-ef-6-and-code-first-migra)) and for implementing `Seed` I need access to classes from `IdentityConfig.cs (ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationRoleManager)` from `Project.WebUI`. Unfortunately, It again will create **cyclic dependence.**

**My question is what to do:
How properly to divide solution on projects and locate `Identity 2.0` files? 
And why `Seed` method from `ApplicationDbInitilizer` not working?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we're trying to do exactly the same thing Sleepy, and I'm in the same boat as you.  I'll fill you in with what I tried.

First off, you can fix the cyclic dependence by moving the ApplicationDbInitializer to the Application_Start method and calling Database.SetInitializer.

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }
```

This lets you keep the ApplicationDbContext and the ApplicationUser in the Domain, while leaving the ApplicationDbInitializer in the WebUI project.

Second, I had read a previous post that said to not use the GetOwinContext methods to get the userManager and the roleManager, but not sure how good of an idea that is.  But at least that let's me get one step further.

[Moving Identity 2.0 functions to repository class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861196/moving-identity-2-0-functions-to-repository-class)

```
    public static void InitializeIdentityForEf(ApplicationDbContext context) {
        // var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        // var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();

        // Since we needed to move this class into the Domain namespace, we have to do the Owin differently

        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
```

The seed isn't populating when I do 'Update-Database', but it does try to run when I run the website and attempt to register a user.  But I get an error

```
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

on this line

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```