# Call UserManager From Data Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using identity 1.0 for my application and want to move `UserManager` to Data layer such as the following code (I've Customized `Userstore` to `AppUserStore`):

```
public class UserRepository
{
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> AppUserManager()
     {
        using (var db=new DataContext())
       {
         var Appstore = new AppUserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
         var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>(Appstore);
         return userManager;
       }
     }
}
```

and then in business Layer i want to use this `userManager` to create a user:

```
 public bool Create(CreateUserViewModel quser)
    {
     var repository = new UserRepository();
     var userManager = repository.AppUserManager();
     var result = userManager.Create(quser);
     return result.IsCompleted
    {
```

but it threw an exception that `DataContext` is disposed.
how can i Move `userManager` to Data Layer and fix this problem? i always use this pattern for my Apps.

Comment: Maybe this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861196/moving-identity-2-0-functions-to-repository-class?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: No, it wants to use UserManager in the business layer but for me is something else, I want to use the  UserManager in Data Layer but it's disposed.

Comment: @mhadi-taghdidi I dont any more idea. I think you must implement it custom ,without `asp.net-identity`